# Angular 2 subscribing to a service which is subscribed to another async function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am trying to develop an Angular application where there is a situation I am calling a service that is subscribed to HTTP service. I have written an alert prompt service which internally calls the HTTP service when "ok" is pressed. Like this:

```
this.alertservice.prompt(url);
```

This will prompt the user for confirmation. If the user clicks "ok", the alert service will call the HTTP service internally:

```
this.httpservice.get(url).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Now I want to inform the parent caller whether the call failed or succeeded. Something like:

```
 this.alertservice.prompt(url).subscribe(res => {
   console.log("success or failure");
 });
```

But I am not understanding how to subscribe to the alert function. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
import {..., EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

export class AlertService {

     ...

     prompt(url:string): Observable<boolean> {

         let result = new EventEmitter<boolean();

         this.httpService.get(url).subscribe
             (
             (res) => {
               console.log("OK:", res);
               result.emit(true);
               result.complete();
             },
             (error) => {
               console.log("ERROR:", error);
               result.emit(false);
               result.complete();
             }
         );
         return result;
     }
}
```

now you can subscribe to the prompt()-function:

```
this.alertService.promp(url).subscribe((okOrNotOk) => {
     // okOrNotOk will be true, when the url was retrieved successfully, 
     // otherwise false
});
```

I'm not an expert on rxjs, perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Please update the answer if you find a better answer so that anyone searching for this get benefited

Comment: it is not rxjs way. You should use build in error notification methods (such as second callback in subscribe) instead of bool callback argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`do`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html#collapseRxJS) in child service and [`catch`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html) for error handling in the parent.

```
child() {
  return this.httpservice.get(url).do(res=>
    {console.log(res)}
  ).catch(e => {
    console.log("handle error");
  });
}

parent() {
  this.child(url).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log("success");
  }, e => {
    console.log("or failure");
  });
}
```

Comment: actually cant handle error  in the parent component as its sweetalert callback and most of the code has been written based on this service already.I have to do the error handling in alert component and send a string or bool value to parent.Is it possible ?